# Is it possible to add credits to user's Google Play account?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm working on an app that upon successfully completing a particular task, the app credits $1 USD to the user's Google Play account as a "reward".

Pretty similar to "[Google Opinion Rewards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.paidtasks&hl=en)", but without surveys.

I've been googling around for anything remotely similar, but I haven't been able to find anything relevant.

So I'm just wondering if this is even possible through public APIs?

Comment: Push comes to shove, you could always use PayPal. Free money will probably be worth the effort for most people.

Comment: That was my initial approach, but then one of the stakeholders wanted me to research the possibility to just do in-store credit.

Comment: A reward app ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapcash.tapcash) says in its description that it can give play store credit, so it appears to be at least possible.